# Считать 2-байтное слово из области данных BIOS на C/C++

Tags: c++, c, bios

Как считать 2-байтное слово из области данных BIOS по адресу 0040:0010 на C/C++?

ОС: Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Зависит от операционной системы

Comment: В Windows два варианта, или из под ring-0 (уровень драйвера), или из под емуляции DOS. эмулятор симитирует поведение BIOS

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как считать слово из области данных BIOS на C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1054021/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-bios-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Comment: К сожелению, в новом вопросе ответ более внятный чем в даном.

Answer (score 3):

Если речь идёт не о защищённом режиме работы процессора, то чтение данных должно осуществляться через длинный (`far`) указатель на область памяти.

**UPDATE** Очень важно: если ваша программа написана для работы в защищённом режиме, в частности, под Windows семейства NT, этот ответ неверен.

Адрес `XXXX:YYYY` записывается на C/C++ в виде 0xXXXXYYYYul, поэтому код будет таким:

```
unsigned short* word_ptr = (far unsigned short *)0x00400010ul;
unsigned short word = *word_ptr;
```

или

```
unsigned short word = word_ptr[0];
```

Возможна проблема в приведённом коде, связанная с тем, что некоторые компиляторы могут трактовать `short` как 32-битовое число, а не как 16-битовое. По моему, так никто не делает, но память может меня подвести.

Стандарт требует только, чтобы размер `short` был не менее 16-ти битов.

Можете завести макрос, который будет обнулять все биты параметра кроме младших шестнадцати для решения этой проблемы.

Comment: Не работает. Нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу. 0x00400010

Comment: Адрес выводит, но при попытке вывода значения - ошибка

Comment: Если вы пишите Windows-приложение, то вообще в эту память не можете обратиться, если только разрабатываете не драйвер. Windows работает в *защищённом* режиме.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko добавьте в начале вопроса, что сборка должна быть для 16-битного DOS, потому что не сразу понятно о чём речь.

Comment: @nick_n_a, добавил. Но там сразу было написано, что ответ не про защищённый режим.

Comment: В с++ нету опции "не про защищённый режим". Новички могут и не знать что это, а более продвинутые - забывать что есть защищённый режим, защищённый режим - это вообще работа с селекторами, таблицей cr3, регистрами, механизмом защиты. Да, windows работает в защищенном режиме, но не разрешает использовать механизмы защиты явно и гибко. Отрицание в данном случае вводит в заблуждение.

Answer (score -2):

Mожно использовать функцию `memcpy`. Открываете нужный диск для чтения, сдвигаете указатель в нужную точку и просто читаете нужное число байт.

Comment: С одной стороны memcpy используется для работы с памятью. Как вы собрались читать с диска с помощью этой функции абсолютно не ясно. И причем тут вообще диск, если вопрос задан исключительно про область конфигурации BIOS, расположенную в оперативной памяти

Comment: У каждого диска первые 512 байт. Это BIOS Parameter Block. Который вполне можно использовать для получения BIOS-информации диска. А чтение достаточно просто реализуется через ios.

Comment: А в вопросе речь про BIOS Data Area http://stanislavs.org/helppc/bios_data_area.html И если конкретнее, то всего о 2х байтах по смещению 0x410 от начала ОЗУ. В которых лежит конфигурация периферийных устройств. И никакого отношения в загрузчику и таблице разделов диска это не имеет