# Как считать слово из области данных BIOS на C++

Tags: c++

Как считать 2-байтное слово из области данных BIOS по адресу 0040:0010 на C/C++?

ОС: Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Считать 2-байтное слово из области данных BIOS на C/C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/466746/%d0%a1%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-bios-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c-c)

Comment: `0040:0010` - это что за адрес такой? DOS real mode?

Comment: @AnT http://dos4gw.org/0_410h_Equipment_List

Comment: @MSDN.'ReinstateMonica'Knight поскольку тут ответ лучше... думаю дубликат наоборот.

Comment: @nick_n_a Я не вижу, чем лучше. Принципиально лучший ответ, на мой взгляд, был бы тот, который содержал рабочий код + конкретные инструкции, как и чем его собрать и запустить, хотя бы для одного из способов (сценарий "DosBox + древняя версия Borland C++", думаю, будет проще всего). Если кто-то опубликует что-то подобное, отзову голос и проголосую наоборот.

Comment: После третьего прочтения ответа там - понял что очень спорно где лучше. Может их как-то соиденить вместе?

Comment: @MSDN.'ReinstateMonica'Knight - я не вижу в этом целесообразности. Я вижу в авторе вопроса студента политеха (или подобного заборостроительного) с методичкой 1998 года рОзлива в лапках, который жаждет решить лабораторку. 
Но да, из любви к искусству можно скомпилировать из нескольких ответов нечто более близкое к идеалу.

Answer (score 2):

Из приложения под Windows это сделать невозможно, хотя бы потому, что семейство WINDOWS NT, к которому относится и Windows 10, подменяет собой BIOS в его классическом понимании.

То есть да, можно написать программу на C/С++, но компилировать ее надо будет под DOS, чтобы она выполнялась в реальном режиме процессора и имела доступ ко всем ресурсам. Под вендой такая программа будет работать в режиме эмуляции реального режима внутри защищенного, для чего понадобится DOSBOX, либо виртуалка с DOS.

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю от себя. Ответ gbg - верный, есть более тернистые способы, добавлю немного о них

1. Из под уровня драйвера, используя специальные АПИ можно прочитать память BIOS, драйвер связывается с приложением через DeviceIoControl информацию можно передать на уровень software. Читать изучать Driver Development Kit + проблемы - может понадобится админский доступ.
2. Зная что бывает [1] можно либо случайно в хакерских тулзах, или долго нудно случайно найти библиотеку которая позволяет считать память ВIOS, и пользуясь ею считать (будет плюс dll и плюс файл драйвера).
3. 16-битные windows-приложения и dll имеют доступ к данному участку памяти для совместимости в режиме эмуляции. В WinXP это работало без проблем, за 7 и 10 не могу сказать. Старички 16-битные windows-приложений - winhelp.exe из WinXP, msword 6-той версии и ниже.  Так же есть некоторые популярные софтины, например DOP (digital orkestrator). Писать такие приложение позволяют старые версии компилятора borland, delphi 1-й версии, и т п.
4. Емуляция DOS, под 64-бита скорее всего понадобится DOSBOX
5. Возможно (если это разрешено) можно загрузиться с старенького "реанимаитора" DOS, и написав под DOS софтину без проблем её запустить. Более сложный вариант - свой загрузчик.

Comment: NTVDM, который позволял запускать программы в реалмоде, был викинут после Windows XP, так что остается только dosbox

Comment: @gbg я уже думаю перенести ответ в дубль, или нетрогать ничего...

Comment: @gbg - я думаю, у модераторов есть нужный инструментарий, это их дело, наводить порядок. Должность у них такая.

Comment: NTVDM в 32-разрядных версиях современной Windows, насколько я знаю, все еще доступен (его нужно лишь включить в компонентах Windows). Но вопрос про x64 Windows, так что да, этот сценарий не подходит.

Comment: Играем в ЧГКашное - "Дайте максимально точный ответ". Даю: NTVDM был выкинут из стандартной поставки.